# Cannot install stack-run

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Per instructions on page https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UCL.haskelly , I'm  trying:

```
% stack build stack-run
stack-run-0.1.1.4: configure
stack-run-0.1.1.4: build

--  While building custom Setup.hs for package stack-run-0.1.1.4 using:
      /home/mark/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.2.0.1_ghc-8.4.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/mark/haskell/hl1/.stack-work/logs/stack-run-0.1.1.4.log

    Configuring stack-run-0.1.1.4...
    Preprocessing executable 'stack-run' for stack-run-0.1.1.4..
    Building executable 'stack-run' for stack-run-0.1.1.4..

    /tmp/stack2483/stack-run-0.1.1.4/unix/System/Console/Questioner.hs:4:14: warning:
        -XOverlappingInstances is deprecated: instead use per-instance pragmas OVERLAPPING/OVERLAPPABLE/OVERLAPS
      |
    4 | {-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances  #-}
      |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [1 of 5] Compiling System.Console.Questioner.Autocomplete ( unix/System/Console/Questioner/Autocomplete.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/stack-run/stack-run-tmp/System/Console/Questioner/Autocomplete.o )
    [2 of 5] Compiling System.Console.Questioner.Util ( unix/System/Console/Questioner/Util.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/stack-run/stack-run-tmp/System/Console/Questioner/Util.o )
    [3 of 5] Compiling System.Console.Questioner.ProgressIndicators ( unix/System/Console/Questioner/ProgressIndicators.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/stack-run/stack-run-tmp/System/Console/Questioner/ProgressIndicators.o )
    [4 of 5] Compiling System.Console.Questioner ( unix/System/Console/Questioner.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/stack-run/stack-run-tmp/System/Console/Questioner.o )
    [5 of 5] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/stack-run/stack-run-tmp/Main.o )

    /tmp/stack2483/stack-run-0.1.1.4/src/Main.hs:18:1: error:
        Could not find module ‘Distribution.PackageDescription.Parse’
        Perhaps you meant
          Distribution.PackageDescription.Parsec (from Cabal-2.2.0.1)
          Distribution.PackageDescription.Check (from Cabal-2.2.0.1)
          Distribution.PackageDescription.Quirks (from Cabal-2.2.0.1)
        Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
       |
    18 | import           Distribution.PackageDescription.Parse
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

OS: Debian 9 x64

I just installed `stack` today and created new project.

`stack` complained about some packages, so per Recommended actions I added following to `stack.yaml`:

```
extra-deps: [conduit-1.2.13.1, conduit-extra-1.1.17, resourcet-1.1.11, streaming-commons-0.1.19]
```

Stack version:

```
% stack --version
Version 1.7.1, Git revision 681c800873816c022739ca7ed14755e85a579565 (5807 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.28.2





name:                hl1
version:             0.1.0.0
github:              "githubuser/hl1"
license:             BSD3
author:              "Author name here"
maintainer:          "example@example.com"
copyright:           "2018 Author name here"

extra-source-files:
- README.md
- ChangeLog.md

# Metadata used when publishing your package
# synopsis:            Short description of your package
# category:            Web

# To avoid duplicated efforts in documentation and dealing with the
# complications of embedding Haddock markup inside cabal files, it is
# common to point users to the README.md file.
description:         Please see the README on GitHub at <https://github.com/githubuser/hl1#readme>

dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5

library:
  source-dirs: src

executables:
  hl1-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - hl1

tests:
  hl1-test:
    main:                Spec.hs
    source-dirs:         test
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - hl1
```

Comment: What is your `stack --version` output?, and what is your package.yaml? I did stack build stack-run using 1.7.1 on macos, it worked

Comment: @YuanWang added the info

Comment: It seems you haven’t changed the package.yaml. What about stack.yaml or cabal file?  Which libraries you intent to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is indicated here:

```
    Could not find module ‘Distribution.PackageDescription.Parse’
```

`stack-run` has not been updated to support being built against modern versions of `Cabal`. That module was removed as of Cabal 2.2.

There is an open PR on the `stack-run` repo which addresses this issue:

https://github.com/yamadapc/stack-run/pull/15/files#diff-f8f3412da88cd4806f23d59fe59ebc3bR19

Comment: Just great... Haskelly extension page requires me explicitly to install `stack-run`: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UCL.haskelly I'm not even sure at this point if I really need it for that extension to work.

Comment: @LetMeSOThat4U coming from Haskelly steps to here. Any updates? Did you find a soltution?